# Urllib and urllib2 returns "IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known" but Firefox downloads file with no trouble

Tags: python, download, urllib

I am trying to download GRIB data (binary weather forecast data) from the National Weather Service.  I have written Python code to format the HTTP string to get data for today, looking 12 hours ahead.

The Python code returns the HTTP string, then attempts to use urllib.urlopen to download the data.  Now, if I paste the HTTP string into Firefox, the GRIB file downloads.  If I try to use urllib.urlopen, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dantayaga/bovine_aerospace/dev/grib_get.py", line 67, in <module>
webf=urllib.urlopen(griburl)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
return opener.open(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 207, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 344, in open_http
h.endheaders(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 757, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Here is the HTTP string I am using:

http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_hd.pl?file=gfs.t06z.mastergrb2f12&lev_1000_mb=on&lev_975_mb=on&lev_950_mb=on&lev_925_mb=on&lev_900_mb=on&lev_850_mb=on&lev_800_mb=on&lev_750_mb=on&lev_700_mb=on&lev_650_mb=on&lev_600_mb=on&lev_550_mb=on&lev_500_mb=on&lev_450_mb=on&lev_400_mb=on&lev_350_mb=on&lev_300_mb=on&lev_250_mb=on&lev_200_mb=on&lev_150_mb=on&lev_100_mb=on&lev_70_mb=on&lev_30_mb=on&lev_20_mb=on&lev_10_mb=on&var_HGT=on&var_RH=on&var_TMP=on&var_UGRD=on&var_VGRD=on&var_VVEL=onleftlon=-90rightlon=90toplat=90bottomlat-90&dir=%2Fgfs.2012070706%2Fmaster

If you are testing this string in Firefox and it's not working, change "20120707" to today's date and "06" to "00" and it should work.

My question is simple (I think): why does this work in Firefox and not with urllib?

Here is the code I use to generate the http string and then attempt to download the result:

```
#Get GRIB files

import urllib

forecast_time='06' #What time the forecast is (00, 06, 12, 18)
forecast_hours='12' #How many hours ahead to forecast (2 or 3 digits)
forecast_date='20120707' #What date the forecast is for yyyymmdd

top_lat=90 #Top of bounding box (North)
bottom_lat=-90 #Bottom of bounding box (South)
left_lon=-90 #Left of bounding box (West)
right_lon=90 #Right of bounding box (East)

griburl='http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_hd.pl?'
griburl=griburl+'file=gfs.t'+str(forecast_time)+'z.mastergrb2f'
griburl=griburl+forecast_hours

#Select atmospheric levels

griburl=griburl+'&lev_1000_mb=on'  #1000 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_975_mb=on'   #975 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_950_mb=on'   #950 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_925_mb=on'   #925 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_900_mb=on'   #900 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_850_mb=on'   #850 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_800_mb=on'   #800 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_750_mb=on'   #750 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_700_mb=on'   #700 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_650_mb=on'   #650 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_600_mb=on'   #600 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_550_mb=on'   #550 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_500_mb=on'   #500 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_450_mb=on'   #450 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_400_mb=on'   #400 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_350_mb=on'   #350 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_300_mb=on'   #300 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_250_mb=on'   #250 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_200_mb=on'   #200 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_150_mb=on'   #150 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_100_mb=on'   #100 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_70_mb=on'    #70 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_30_mb=on'    #30 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_20_mb=on'    #20 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_10_mb=on'    #10 mb level

#Select variables

griburl=griburl+'&var_HGT=on'  #Height (geopotential m)
griburl=griburl+'&var_RH=on'  #Relative humidity (%)
griburl=griburl+'&var_TMP=on' #Temperature (K)
griburl=griburl+'&var_UGRD=on' #East-West component of wind (m/s)
griburl=griburl+'&var_VGRD=on' #North-South component of wind (m/s)
griburl=griburl+'&var_VVEL=on' #Vertical Windspeed (Pa/s)

#Select bounding box

griburl=griburl+'leftlon='+str(left_lon)
griburl=griburl+'rightlon='+str(right_lon)
griburl=griburl+'toplat='+str(top_lat)
griburl=griburl+'bottomlat'+str(bottom_lat)

#Select date and time

griburl=griburl+'&dir=%2Fgfs.'+forecast_date+forecast_time+'%2Fmaster'
print(griburl)
print('Downloading GRIB file for date '+forecast_date+' time ' +forecast_time + ',    forecasting '+forecast_hours+' hours ahead...')
webf=urllib.urlopen(griburl)
local_filename=forecast_date+'_'+forecast_time+'_'+forecast_hours+'.grib'
localf=open('//home//dantayaga//bovine_aerospace//grib//data//'+local_filename, 'wb')
localf.write(webf.read())
print('Requested grib data written to file '+local_filename)
```

Any help is most appreciated.  Is there a formatting error that Firefox is catching or something?

Comment: Works on my machine, I had to remove your hardcoded filename for writing. Why are there double slashes in the path name? What version of python are you running? 
As a side note, that code is pretty strange to read... All of those giburl reassignments could be condensed ```''.join(['&lev_%s' % level for level in [1000,975,950,925,850,800,750,700,650,600,550,500,450,400,350,300,250,200,150,100,70,30,20,10]])```

Comment: You're missing a `=` after `bottomlat`. However it would be more pythonic to create a dictionary of all the GET variables, and then use `urllib.urlencode`. I imagine this would also handle escaping of characters better, which could cause problems.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.3.  I appreciate the formatting comments, etc.  @wcdolphin I am not sure why it is working on your machine and not on mine.  Perhaps it is my computer and not the code that is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
import urllib2
import urllib

url = 'http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_hd.pl'

forecast_time = '06' #What time the forecast is (00, 06, 12, 18)
forecast_hours = '09' #How many hours ahead to forecast (2 or 3 digits)
forecast_date = '20120705' #What date the forecast is for yyyymmdd

get_parameters = {
    'subregion':'',
    'toplat':90, #Top of bounding box (North)
    'bottomlat':-90, #Bottom of bounding box (South)
    'leftlon':-90, #Left of bounding box (West)
    'rightlon':90, #Right of bounding box (East)
}

get_parameters['file'] = 'gfs.t' + forecast_time + 'z.mastergrb2f' + forecast_hours

on_variables = [
    'lev_1000_mb',
    'lev_975_mb',
    'lev_950_mb',
    'lev_925_mb',
    'lev_900_mb',
    'lev_850_mb',
    'lev_800_mb',
    'lev_750_mb',
    'lev_700_mb',
    'lev_650_mb',
    'lev_600_mb',
    'lev_550_mb',
    'lev_500_mb',
    'lev_450_mb',
    'lev_400_mb',
    'lev_350_mb',
    'lev_300_mb',
    'lev_250_mb',
    'lev_200_mb',
    'lev_150_mb',
    'lev_100_mb',
    'lev_70_mb',
    'lev_30_mb',
    'lev_20_mb',
    'lev_10_mb',

    'var_HGT',  #Height (geopotential m)
    'var_RH',  #Relative humidity (%)
    'var_TMP', #Temperature (K)
    'var_UGRD', #East-West component of wind (m/s)
    'var_VGRD', #North-South component of wind (m/s)
    'var_VVEL' #Vertical Windspeed (Pa/s)
]

get_parameters.update(dict((param, 'on') for param in on_variables))

#Select date and time
get_parameters['dir'] = '/gfs.' + forecast_date + forecast_time + '/master'

print('Downloading GRIB file for date '+forecast_date+' time ' +forecast_time + ',    forecasting '+forecast_hours+' hours ahead...')

req = urllib2.urlopen(url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(get_parameters), timeout = 300) # Theres bug in apache for non-used GET varaibles so we have to manually add them to the url ...
local_filename = forecast_date + '_' + forecast_time + '_' + forecast_hours + '.grib'
local_file = open('/home/dantayaga/bovine_aerospace/grib/data/' + local_filename, 'wb')

local_file.write(req.read())
local_file.close()

print('Requested grib data written to file ' + local_filename)
```

I've tested it with another file since the one you had in your original code, doesn't exist I get:

> Data file is not present: /pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2012070706/master27/gfs.t06z.mastergrb2f12

try to use dictionaries, list, tuples or other complex data structures to store your parameters, this way you'll be able to detect subtle bugs much sooner, and reduce duplicate code.

`urllib2.urlopen` has an optional parameter called `data` thats used to pass parameter but unfortunately theres a bug in either apache or python  since I keep getting `raise IncompleteRead(value)`

[httplib: incomplete read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670257/httplib-incomplete-read)
http://bugs.python.org/issue14044

Comment: Hmm...your code worked for me this morning and I downloaded the data I needed...but now I am getting the same "Name or service not known".  Strange.  I think this might be a problem with the website I am downloading from rather than Python.

Comment: I am going to mark this post as "answered" and investigate this question further through the NOAA website.  Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @glossarch interesting I also work with NOAA data mostly MODIS data sets, are you on windows? did you copy/paste and still get this error?

Comment: you can also try `import os
os.environ['http_proxy']=''` and check ur dns settings.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu precise.  I'll try using the os option you recommend.  There are perl and sh scripts on the NOMADS website for downloading data, but since the model I am using will be in pure Python I want everything to stay consistent.  Plus this *should* work with Python...