# POST request to Heroku results in Python IncompleteRead Error

Tags: python, heroku, http-post, python-requests

My Python script, with lines:

```
from requests import post

...
while(1):

   result = readSensors().result

   payload["z"] = (result['zforce'])
   payload["x"] = (result['xforce'])
   payload["y"] = (result['yforce'])
   payload["light"] = (result['light'] )
   payload["pitch"] = ( result["pitch"] )
   payload["azimuth"] = ( result["azimuth"] )
   payload["roll"] = ( result["roll"] )

   post(SERVER, data = payload )
   sleep(0.02)
```

to my Heroku webapp server results in a Python error `httplib.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)` error.

---

The `web.js` file looks like:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){     
  if (request.method == 'POST'){
            var body = '';
            request.on('data', function (data) {
                body += data;
            });
            request.on('end', function () {
                //send data to clients.
                io.sockets.emit( 'data', parse(body) );

            });
    response.end()

}
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);


var io = io.listen(server);

io.set('log level', 1);
io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10);  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more likely to be an issue with your "webapp server" rather than your client code, so you'll have to include more info about the server.

One common reason for this is that you're sending back a response with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, but not providing a response body which is [chunk-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) correctly.

For example, the following server code...

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class MyRequestHander(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_bogus_response()

    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_bogus_response()

    def send_bogus_response(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        self.send_header('Connection', 'close')
        self.send_header('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
        self.end_headers()

server = HTTPServer(('', 8000), MyRequestHander)
server.serve_forever()
```

...will cause the same error when called with the `requests` library...

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.post('http://localhost:8000', data={'foo':'bar'})
...
httplib.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)
```

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670257/httplib-incomplete-read), this problem can also happen if the server doesn't read the entire request body, and there's probably a few other reasons as to why this could be happening, but I can't be sure which is most likely without knowing more about the server setup.

---

**Update**

There's quite a few issues with the `web.js` code, but the main problem is that you're sending back a response before having read the POST data. The `response.end()` needs to go inside the `request.on('end', ...)` function, otherwise neither of your `request.on(...)` functions will ever get called.

The following code should eliminate that problem...

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response)
{
    if (request.method == 'POST')
    {
        var body = '';

        request.on('data', function(data)
        {
            body += data;
        });

        request.on('end', function()
        {
            //send data to clients.
            io.sockets.emit('data', parse(body));
            response.end();
        });
    }
});
```

...although I'm not sure what the `parse(...)` function is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added some more information about the server. I'll try your suggestions tomorrow.

Comment: thanks! Here's the project if you are curious what you help on: 
http://artech.herokuapp.com/